# Python - random.randint () issue

Tags: python, random, int

After randomly generating a number, I check to see if the user's input matches. If it does, print one line, if not, print another. Even if the user guesses correctly, the other line prints.

```
chosenNumber = input ("Choose a number: ")
int (chosenNumber)
diceRoll = random.randint (1,3)
print ("The number rolled is: ",diceRoll)
if diceRoll == chosenNumber:
      print ("WINNER")
else:
      print ("LOSER")
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What's your question? What happens, and what were you expecting to happen? (Also, `int(chosenNumber)` won't do anything useful if you don't store the integer anywhere.)

Comment: Kudos for knowing that you can't compare a string to an integer and that you have to use `int()` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int()` does not turn the string to an integer in place because strings are immutable.

You can do:

```
chosenNumber = int(input ("Choose a number: "))
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I knew I could cast it to an int. At first I had chosenNumber = input (int("Choose a number: ")).